# clang version 3.8.0 clang++ 'type_traits' file not found

Tags: c++, macos, clang, clang++

I am using OSX 10.11 and I installed LLVM and clang from llvm.org

```
/usr/local/bin/clang++ -v
clang version 3.8.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git e2c22771566f2f28db1f4a9b2b0191ff9f2ae90c) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 7a2d52ce5de3372b030c296bbfe70dedb29b46d3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
```

However, when I try to build something, an error occurred:

```
/usr/local/bin/clang++ -I. -c -g -O2 -fno-rtti `llvm-config --cxxflags` -o 
LoopExtractAction.o LoopExtractAction.cpp
In file included from LoopExtractAction.cpp:15:
In file included from ./LoopExtractAction.h:20:
In file included from /usr/local/include/clang/Lex/MacroInfo.h:18:
In file included from /usr/local/include/clang/Lex/Token.h:18:
In file included from /usr/local/include/clang/Basic/SourceLocation.h:18:
In file included from /usr/local/include/clang/Basic/LLVM.h:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:19:
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/type_traits.h:17:10: fatal error: 'type_traits'
      file not found
#include <type_traits>
```

It seems that `llvm/Support/type_traits.h` includes `type_traits`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you include the `-std=c++11` flag?

Comment: @Rufflewind add that flag the error still exists. I think clang supports c++11 automatically?

Comment: You might be missing the search paths for [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) headers, if it is even installed at all.

Comment: Yes, I have to -I/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 manually. That's weird.

Comment: It's not aware of them since they were installed as separate packages.  You can put them in `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to avoid having to add them manually.